# My NBA 2k20 game won't download

Tags: nba2k20

I have NBA 2k20 on disc but when I try to download it to play it, the game keeps on getting corrupted and I can't play it. Also when I go to my friends list it says view in PS store and when I go to the PS store it's making me buy it again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this happens to me all the time. My suggestion is restarting the station. If that doesn’t work, take the disc out and put it back in.